# Iterating a list until the list is empty

Tags: java, list, loops, iterator, empty-list

I'm trying to iterate a list, wherein each iteration I'm doing one of the below:

- Continue to next element (by some logic)
- Removing the current element

What I need is that after I'm iterating through all the items, it will continue to iterate until the list is empty (the logic ensures all elements will be removed).

Problem is that after the iterator iterates all the list elements, it didn't continue to run on the elements I didn't remove:

```
List<Integer> lst = new ArrayList();
lst.add(1);
lst.add(2);
lst.add(3);

Iteartor<Integer> iterator = lst.listIterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()){
    Integer curInt = iterator.next();
    if (!passTest(curInt)){
        continue;
    }
    iterator.remove();
}
```

IMPORTANT NOTE: `passTest(curInt)` logic can be different for each iteration. It means that iteration one can cause `continue`, then the second and third iterations will cause a removal. PROBLEM is I'm expecting for a fourth iteration (on the first item that wasn't removed).

The solution I've found:

```
List<Integer> lst = new ArrayList();
lst.add(1);
lst.add(2);
lst.add(3);

Iteartor<Integer> iterator = lst.listIterator();
while (!lst.isEmpty()){

    Integer curInt;
    if (iteration.hasNext()){
        curInt = iterator.next();
    } else {
        curInt = lst.get(0);
    }

    if (!passTest(curInt)){
        continue;
    }

    iterator.remove();
}
```

Is that the right way to achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your solution doesn't seem correct. You will first iterate over all the elements of the `List`, possibly removing some of them. Once you finish iterating over the `List`, `iteration.hasNext()` will always return `false`, so you'll keep getting the first element (due to `curInt = lst.get(0)`). If you remove that first element, you'll get a different element the next time `curInt = lst.get(0)` is executed, so the `List` will become empty in the end, but that doesn't seem like the desired behavior (if it was the desired behavior, you could eliminate the `Iterator` and just keep getting the first element in a loop and possibly removing it).

You should use nested loops, and re-create the `Iterator` instance inside the outer loop:

```
while (!lst.isEmpty()) {
    Iteartor<Integer> iterator = lst.listIterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Integer curInt = iterator.next();
        if (passTest(curInt)) {
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Each iteration of the outer loop creates an `Iterator` and performs the inner loop.

Each iteration of the inner loop iterates over the elements of the `List`, and possibly removes some of them.

Once you finish an iteration over the `List`, you must create a new `Iterator` in order to iterate over the remaining elements again.